# Invoked function from setTimeout shows incorrect React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm running into a weird condition where all of my toast messages are deleted after the first setTimeout runs. Can anyone please explain why this is the case?  What's extremely weird is that if I console.log `toasters` in `removeToaster`, it only shows one toaster (i.e the first toaster). However, the console.log that runs at the top level shows all of the toasters in the array.

Thanks so much!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const SuccessToaster = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      props.removeToaster(props.id);
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, []);

  return <h1>{props.message}</h1>
}

const App = () => {
  const [toasters, setToasters] = useState([]);

  console.log(toasters);

  const addNewToaster = () => {
    setToasters([...toasters, {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      message: 'Hello World'
    }]);
  }

  const removeToaster = id => {
    setToasters(toasters.filter(toaster => toaster.id !== id))
  }

  const clearToasters = () => {
    setToasters([]);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={addNewToaster}>Add Toaster</button>
      <button onClick={clearToasters}>Clear Toasters</button>
      {toasters.map((toast, i) => <SuccessToaster key={toast.id} removeToaster={removeToaster} {...toast} />)}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a given `SuccessToaster` is created, the `removeToaster` that its containing effect hook has a reference to is the one passed in on the initial render of the toast. On that initial render, no other toasts currently exist, so this function:

```
  const removeToaster = id => {
    setToasters(toasters.filter(toaster => toaster.id !== id))
  }
```

closes over a `toasters` variable which may not be up-to-date when the timeout runs.

If you create another toast, the effect hook inside the *first* `SuccessToaster` won't run again, so the `props.removeToaster` won't get updated to include the new state in its closure.

Use a callback in `removeToaster` instead:

```js
const SuccessToaster = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      props.removeToaster(props.id);
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, []);

  return <h1>{props.message}</h1>
}

const App = () => {
  const [toasters, setToasters] = React.useState([]);
  const addNewToaster = () => {
    setToasters([...toasters, {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      message: 'Hello World'
    }]);
  }

  const removeToaster = id => {
    setToasters(toasters => toasters.filter(toaster => toaster.id !== id))
  }

  const clearToasters = () => {
    setToasters([]);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={addNewToaster}>Add Toaster</button>
      <button onClick={clearToasters}>Clear Toasters</button>
      {toasters.map((toast, i) => <SuccessToaster key={toast.id} removeToaster={removeToaster} {...toast} />)}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate your response! Just curious but when removeToaster is passed to the first toaster and it has 'closed' off the toasters variable, since toasters is an array, wouldn't the reference be the same when removeToaster is called? That would mean that it should contain the same toasters that the top level console.log shows.

Comment: Every time `App` is invoked, a new binding for `toasters` is created. Sub-components will not update their associated bindings if the effect hook uses an empty dependency array, since such an array indicates to run the effect only on mount. Even though the top App has the updated state now, the effect with the timeout doesn't get updated or re-calculated on a re-render.

Comment: Omg that makes perfect sense. It completely slipped my mind that addNewToaster (and subsequently setToasters) is creating a brand new array which is changing the reference. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting `stale closure data`, try this:

```
  const addNewToaster = () => {
    setToasters(oldValues => ([...oldValues, {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      message: 'Hello World'
    }]));
  }

  const removeToaster = id => {
    setToasters((oldValues) =>
      oldValues.filter((toaster) => toaster.id !== id)
    );
  }
```

here is a good article about this issue: [https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#:~:text=The%20stale%20closure%20problem%20occurs,way%20to%20update%20the%20state](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#:%7E:text=The%20stale%20closure%20problem%20occurs,way%20to%20update%20the%20state).

Comment: Definitely a great suggestion. Just curious why this has to be done in the first place since the top level console.log shows the latest version of the toasters array.

Comment: @StockDC2 Check the Article I've added to my answer so you understand what a `stale closure or stale state` is

Comment: Just saw your updated reply. Thanks so much for the link. Really appreciate it!